# Why do record based inductive types with primitive projections lack an eta law?

Tags: coq, inductive-type

In Coq there is ongoing work to shore up some weaknesses in subject reduction and coinductive types. Primitive projections are part of that effort for better behaviour.

I get why there might be complications with eta reduction for coinductive types with primitive projections but what's the problem with inductive types?

For context I'm playing with a minor variant of W types and I basically have to decide between

```
Inductive W {A: Set} (B: A -> Set) :=
| sup s (p: B s -> W B).
```

and

```
Inductive W {A: Set} (B: A -> Set) := sup {
  tag: A ;
  field (ix: B tag): W B ;
}.
```

With primitive projections the latter lacks an eta law.
You can do a sort of variant of an induction principle here but it's more than a little awkward and I don't really understand the how and whys here.

I don't have any evidence for my intuition and the record encoding is a little awkward to use sometimes but my intuition just says the record encoding looks prettier. It definitely might not be the best choice though.

Comment: The actual gory code https://gist.github.com/mstewartgallus/eb35e322bb90f3062393d2ff075e53d7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reduction will not terminate if you give `W` an eta law.  Fixpoints only reduce when applied to constructors.  However, if you have `F : W B -> C` such that `F (sup t f)` reduces to `F_step t f (fun x => F (f x))`, then `F x` would reduce to `F (sup x.(tag) x.(field))` which would reduce to `F_step x.(tag) x.(field) (fun y => F (x.(field) y))`.  Reduction would then continue under binders ad infinitum.

---

We can also consider restricting our attention to just conversion.  Consider a Turing Machine runner that uses `@W unit (fun _ => unit)` for termination fuel and computes whether the Turing Machine halts. Even though the type is uninhabited, `fun fuel => does_it_halt TM fuel` will be convertible with `fun _ => true` whenever TM halts. Hence the eta rule forces conversion to decide the halting problem.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer, since eta laws in Coq are not part of reduction, only in conversion, so I do not think your example would manifest in practice. Also, what should the type of ` F_step` be?

Comment: If the eta law exposes new opportunities for reduction, then reduction cannot be considered complete without the eta law.  That is, if a term of type `unit` is convertible with `tt` but does not reduce to `tt` then we do not have strong normalization.  But my answer works just as well (perhaps even better) if you replace "reduction" with "conversion".  With the eta rule you suggest, you cannot decide in finite time whether or not a given term is convertible with `fun _ => true`.

Comment: Consider a Turing Machine runner that uses `@W unit (fun _ => unit)` for termination fuel and computes whether the Turing Machine halts.  Even though the type is uninhabited, `fun fuel => does_it_halt TM fuel` will be convertible with `fun _ => true` whenever `TM` halts.  Hence the eta rule forces conversion to decide the halting problem.

Comment: (Perhaps I should move this content to the answer itself?)

Comment: And `F_step` is roughly the argument to the induction principle for `W`, it would have type `forall (t : A), (B t -> W B) -> (B t -> C) -> C` (the dependently typed version is of type `forall (t : A) (f : B t -> W B), (forall b : B t, C (f b)) -> C (sup t f)`)

Comment: Perhaps I am asking a silly question, but how do we get from `fun fuel => does_it_halt TM fuel` to `fuel => true`? The $\eta$-rule gets us to `does_it_halt TM`, but then what rule makes progress to `fuel => true`?

Comment: That is $\eta$ for functions.  The $\eta$ rule for the `W` record gets us from `fun fuel => does_it_halt TM fuel` to `fun fuel => does_it_halt TM (sup fuel.(tag) fuel.(field))`.  Then $\iota$ (+ $\beta\delta$) will run the TM one step, blocking on `fuel.(field)`.  But then we can use $\eta$ to expose another `sup` to run the TM another step, etc.  If the TM eventually halts, the body of the function will reduce to `true`.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a relevant question: Why record-based inductive type doesn't allow dependent elimination?   I checked the doc (for negative coind type) it says dependent elimination implies prop eta rules. I think your answer is talking about judgemental ones so I ask here. If this question is not so relevant I can re-create a new question